# Python pre-processing selectors not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, conda

I am building a Conda package on Teamcity. The package will be installed on both Linux and Windows. However, I have some dependencies which need to be installed on Linux and not on Windows. I have added pre processing selectors in the meta.yaml. However, when installing the package on Windows machine I can still see the dependencies being downloaded.

Sample meta.yaml below:

```
requirements:
  build:
    - python
    - pip


  run:
    - python=3.10 
    - bs4
    - krb5  # [not win]
    - python-gssapi # [not win]
```

Is 'run' the right place for the selector? I have tried adding this to build dependency, however, the dependencies do not install on any platform if moved to build?

Comment: Possible whitespace issue? Ensure there are *two spaces* before the hash (`  # [not win]`).